# Can I use a multimeter to verify if RX/TX of a device is working?

Tags: serial, multimeter, low-voltage

To summarize a problem: My electricity meter uses a HAN interface (via M-bus) to transmit the meter's data every 10 seconds. Apparently this HAN interface can be enabled/disabled by my energy provider. I don't receive any data, even though they say it's enabled, when I connect an ESP8266 (Arduino) to the DATA_OUT port on my meter and read any incoming bytes.

As I don't own a logic analyzer or an oscilloscope, I cannot verify that any data is actually being sent.. or can I? Can I use a multimeter to measure the voltage or resistance between GND and TX (DATA_OUT) on my meter, and expect a change every ~10 seconds? All I need is to verify that it's sending any data at all, then I can continue debugging my hardware and code.

Comment: A multimeter will not show serial data, the average DC shift caused by numeric data is going to be too small. Get yourself a 24Mhz logic analyzer (uses Pulseview), they cost $10-20. No one should be without one of these devices in their toolkit. Pulseview can calculate the baud rate, and tell you if the signal is inverted.

Comment: Of course you can measure the M-Bus voltage with a multimeter. But it would be more beneficial if you described how have you connected the M-Bus of the meter to ESP32, what electronics you have between them, or did you just connect the bus wires directly to ESP32?

Comment: @JackCreasey I don't think suggesting connecting a cheap logic anayzer to random buses is a good idea without some knowledge of the bus. Especially if the bus is nominally having 24V to 36V. The bus is on an electric meter and the M-Bus slaves are required to be doubly isolated from mains at least with some meters.

Comment: @Justme the user is already interfacing to the HAN (M-bus) but you are correct I should have noted that the LA is only 5V capable and need to use a high voltage interface. The spec is here: https://www.nek.no/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Aidon-HAN-Interface-Description-v11A-ID-34331.pdf

Comment: @JackCreasey I thought the voltage might be too low, which is why I wanted to ask before trying. Thanks for clarifying. I should also have specified which electricity meter I have, because mine (Kamstrup Omnipower) is only 3.3v on the HAN interface. There's a spec here: https://github.com/tiede/kamstrup-mqtt/blob/main/docs/5512-2584_GB_B1_OMNIPOWER%20HAN%20interface%20specification.pdf

Comment: Speaking of logic analyzers, I might as well get myself one. Would this one suffice? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001621950241.html it's 24 MHz and has 8 channels. It's cheap, but I won't be doing crazy high bitrate analyzing. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Is this activity indicator something you want to temporarily for diagnostics? Or something semi-permanent to monitor the the status of the m-bus long term?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Literally just need to check if my HAN interface (M-bus) is sending data every 10 seconds or not.

Comment: If you have a known good device that sends out M-bus signals, such as a meter in your home, you can try various methods to see if you can detect a signal every ten seconds. Once you have a working method, you can apply that method to your device. Ideally, if you have a device that _reads_ meters, you can verify that it works on a known good meter, then try it on your own M-bus.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Unfortunately I don't have a known good device I can also test with.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Yes, the Aliexpress analyzer is the type I'm talking about. There is a good tutorial on Sparkfun that will lead you through the software installation: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-usb-logic-analyzer-with-sigrok-pulseview/all   .......the Uart decoder should help you find out what data is being sent.

Comment: @JackCreasey Absolutely perfect. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use a multimeter to measure the voltage or resistance between
> GND and TX (DATA_OUT) on my meter, and expect a change every ~10
> seconds?

Yes. Every 10 seconds your meter should send several 8 bit serial data bytes at up to 2400 Bd, which should show on the multimeter as a momentary DC voltage of ~1.7 V (50% of 3.3 V) on average. Depending on how much data is sent in each burst the meter's response may be too slow to show the full voltage change, but it should show *some* change.

This won't tell you *what* data is being sent of course, nor the baud rate or whether it is encrypted. For that you need a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

Comment: Perfect - I will give that a go here in a bit and get back. We'll see if my multimeter is fast enough. I think it has a "max reached" setting, which would come in handy here.

Comment: I am measuring a constant voltage of 3.295 volts between GND and TX (DATA_OUT) on the meter. No fluxuation or anything.. just constant 3.295V

Comment: Most Digital multimeters have particularly slow response due to averaging and RMS filtering for the A/D. You would not expect to be able to see any sensible response to numerical data being sent. .

Comment: @JackCreasey Yeah that's what I thought. I will wait for the logic analyzer to arrive :) Thanks